# Topological field with discontinuous reciprocal?

Tags: general-topology, topological-rings

Does there exist a field with a topology such that addition and multiplication are continuous, but division is not (ignoring dividing by 0, 
i.e. it's not even continuous-where-defined)?

Comment: Interesting question.  What I do know is this:  if the topology is complete metric, then inverse is continuous.

Comment: What I also know is that for every topology there is a smaller topology making 1/x continous (take the induced topology in the projective line). So the question is equivalent to 'is every topological field homeomorphic to its image in its own projective line?'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [group of units in a topological ring](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393303/group-of-units-in-a-topological-ring)

Comment: Yes.  See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393303/group-of-units-in-a-topological-ring.

You can find this in Warner's *Topological Fields* on pg. 113.  In brief, you take the rationals and equip them with a topology in which a neighborhood base of $0$ is given by $n\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$.